\@setpar and hook execution order
I have a command that typesets source code, and the text it produces ends with \par. For simplicity, let say we have
\NewDocumentCommand{\commandFromAPackage}{}{line1\par line2\par}

Sometimes, I envision the code as a part of a sentence, so I would like a newline instead of a paragraph change. I can use the para/before hook to cancel the \parskip and the para/begin hook to say \OmitIndent. However, I want to do this only if the command is not followed by a blank line : in that case, the source code really ends a paragraph, and the next one should have indentation and so on. The nice thing is that the blank line will have a \par token and the cmd/par/after will be executed : I can use this to cancel my other hooks.
So I have devised an \unpar command as follows :
\def\unpar{
  \AddToHookNext{para/before}{\vskip-\parskip}%
  \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\OmitIndent}%
  \AddToHookNext{cmd/par/after}{%
    \ClearHookNext{para/before}%
    \ClearHookNext{para/begin}%
  }%
}

and I wrap the typesetting command to add it at the end :
\NewDocumentCommand{\inputcaml}{om!O{}}{\commandFromAPackage\unpar}
% extra args are because my real thing is of course more complicated

And this works like a charm :
\begin{document}
bliblio
\inputcaml[t]{e.ml}

Should have indentation

\inputcaml[t]{e.ml}
Should not have indentation

blabla

\inputcaml[t]{e.ml}
Should also not have indentation

\inputcaml[t]{e.ml}

Should have indent too.


\inputcaml[t]{e.ml}
Should not have indentation

\end{document}


HOWEVER
For managing a change in left margin, I actually have a \@setpar{{\@@par}}, which I took from the indent package and is aimed at preventing the reset of \parshape after each paragraph.
So my code actually looks like this, with two groups having each a \@setpar :
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand{\commandFromAPackage}{}{line1\par line2\par}
\def\unpar{
  \AddToHookNext{para/before}{\vskip-\parskip}%
  \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\OmitIndent}%
  \AddToHookNext{cmd/par/after}{%
    \ClearHookNext{para/before}%
    \ClearHookNext{para/begin}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\inputcaml}{om!O{}}{\commandFromAPackage\unpar}
\makeatletter  % so we can say \@setpar
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\@setpar{{\@@par}}

bliblio
\inputcaml[t]{e.ml}

blibli

\endgroup


\begingroup
\@setpar{{\@@par}}
blabla

\inputcaml[t]{e.ml}

avec la convention suivante~:
\endgroup

\end{document}

And the result is that, in the second group, the last line is "unparagraphed" as if there had not been a blank line before.

Inserting \typeouts in the hooks shows that

the first time, the cmd/par/after is executed and cancels the others ;
the second time, the execution order is para/before, para/begin then cmd/par/after, which explains the result.

This is obviously an interaction with \@setpar does :

Removing the \@setpar in the second group alleviates the problem.
Removing the \inputcaml in the first group also alleviates the problem in the second bloc.
The \@setpar in the first group seems indifferent.

Can somebody explain what is happening here ? Is this a bug in the hook system ? How should I set up things so it works each time (considering the \inputcaml command may also appear outside of the groups that have \@setpar) ?

sorry but all this snippets can not properly be tested. Make a proper MWE. And why don't you process your code inside a group and redefine \par there it to whatever you want? E.g. {\def\par{blub}line1\par line2\par}

First because the code processing is actually done by a package that I did not write. Second, because I do not actually want to change how \par behaves during that processing, only what happens after the last \par.

Actually, there is no change in the execution order : in the second group, the cmd/par/after hook is not executed at all, what we see in the log is the execution of that hook after the \endgroup, when the definition made by \@setpar is no longer in effect.
What happens is that \@setpar{{\@@par}} crudely redefines \par to be {\@@par} : in doing so, the standard "modern" definition of \par (which is no longer a primitive but a macro, that inter alia deals with para hooks) is destroyed.
In that state, the \AddToHookNext{cmd/par/after} just updates that crude definition to append a call to execute the hook content : {\@@par }\UseHookWithArguments {cmd/par/after}{0}. This is why the mechanism works in the first group.
However, because hook manipulations are global, that new definition of \par remains after the first group is exited, despite \@setpar{{\@@par}} having only a local effect. Which does not exhibit any wrong behaviour here but might do in a more complex example.
In the second group, \@setpar again sets (locally) \par to be {\@@par }. But this time, \AddToHookNext does not upgrade this definition to add \UseHookWithArguments {cmd/par/after}{0}, presumably because it kept track somewhere that this had been done previously (makes sense since we do not want to execute the hooks several times !).
Hence the hook is not called in the second group.
When the second group is exited, the meaning of \par is restored to what it was after the first group was exited, and this means the hook is called.
So my earlier solution (setting a hook on \@@par as well) is not good, because we still have the unwanted effects that are described above.
It is better to eschew the use of \@setpar in favor of… hooks !
By saying
\AddToHook{cmd/par/before}{\begingroup}
\AddToHook{cmd/par/after}{\endgroup}

we will get the same intended effect of making the changes induced by \par local. But it is done by prepending and appending calls to hooks to the modern definition of \par, not by replacing that definition. This is done globally, once and for all.
Because hook manipulations are global, we have to add
\RemoveFromHook{cmd/par/before}
\RemoveFromHook{cmd/par/after}

just before the \endgroups of the example.
